# Idiomatic way of detecting duplicate keys in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

I've just noticed that Ruby doesn't raise an exception or even supply a warning if you supply duplicate keys to a hash:

```
$VERBOSE = true
key_value_pairs_with_duplicates = [[1,"a"], [1, "b"]]
# No warning produced
Hash[key_value_pairs_with_duplicates] # => {1=>"b"}
# Also no warning
hash_created_by_literal_with_duplicate_keys = {1 => "a", 1=> "b"} # => {1=>"b"}
```

For `key_value_pairs_with_duplicates`, I could detect duplicate keys by doing

```
keys = key_value_pairs_with_duplicates.map(&:first)
raise "Duplicate keys" unless keys.uniq == keys
```

Or by doing

```
procedurally_produced_hash = {}
key_value_pairs_with_duplicates.each do |key, value|
  raise "Duplicate key" if procedurally_produced_hash.has_key?(key)
  procedurally_produced_hash[key] = value
end
```

Or

```
hash = Hash[key_value_pairs_with_duplicates]
raise "Duplicate keys" unless hash.length == key_value_pairs_with_duplicates.length
```

But is there an idiomatic way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

`Hash#merge` takes an optional block to define how to handle duplicate keys.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge

Taking advantage of the fact this block is only called on duplicate keys:

```
>> a = {a: 1, b: 2}
=> {:a=>1, :b=>2}

>> a.merge(c: 3) { |key, old, new| fail "Duplicate key: #{key}" }
=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}

>> a.merge(b: 10, c: 3) { |key, old, new| fail "Duplicate key: #{key}" }
RuntimeError: Duplicate key: b
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply build a hash form the array, checking for a value before overwriting a key.  This way it avoid creating any unnecessary temporary collections.

```
def make_hash(key_value_pairs_with_duplicates)
  result = {}
  key_value_pairs_with_duplicates.each do |pair|
    key, value = pair
    raise "Duplicate key" if result.has_key?(key)
    result[key] = value
  end
  result
end
```

But no, I don't think there is an "idiomatic" way to doing this.  It just follows the last in rule, and if you don't like that it's up to you to fix it.

In the literal form you are probably out of luck.  But in the literal form why would you need to validate this? You are not getting it from a dynamic source if it's literal, so if you choose to dupe keys, it's your own fault.  Just, uh... don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two idiomatic ways to handle this:

1. Use one of the Hash extensions that allow multiple values per key, or
2. Extend Hash (or patch w/ flag method) and implement `[]=` to throw a dupe key exception.

You could also just decorate an existing hash with the `[]=` that throws, or `alias_method`--either way, it's straight-forward, and pretty Ruby-ish.

Answer (score 0):

In other answers I've already stated my opinion that Ruby needs a standard method to build a hash from an enumerable. So, as you need your own abstraction for the task anyway, let's just take [Facets' mash](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/doc/api/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-graph) with the implementation you like the most (`Enumerable#inject` + `Hash#update` looks good to me) and add the check:

```
module Enumerable
  def mash
    inject({}) do |hash, item|
      key, value = block_given? ? yield(item) : item
      fail("Repeated key: #{key}") if hash.has_key?(key) # <- new line
      hash.update(key => value)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think most people here overthink the problem. To deal with duplicate keys, I'd simply do this:

```
arr = [ [:a,1], [:b,2], [:c,3] ]
hsh = {}

arr.each do |k,v| 
  raise("Whoa! I already have :#{k} key.") if hsh.has_key?(k)
  x[k] = v
end
```

Or make a method out of this, maybe even extend a Hash class with it. Or create a child of Hash class (UniqueHash?) which would have this functionality by default.

But is it worth it? (I don't think so.) How often do we need to deal with duplicate keys in hash like this?

Answer (score 0):

Latest Ruby versions do supply a warning when duplicating a key. However they still go ahead and re-assign the duplicate's value to the key, which is not always desired behaviour. IMO, the best way to deal with this is to override the construction/assignment methods. E.g. to override `#[]=`

```
class MyHash < Hash
  def []=(key,val)
    if self.has_key?(key)
      puts("key: #{key} already has a value!")
    else
      super(key,val)
    end
  end
end
```

So when you run:

```
h = MyHash.new
h[:A] = ['red']
h[:B] = ['green']
h[:A] = ['blue']
```

it will output

```
key: A already has a value!
{:A=>["red"], :B=>["green"]}
```

Of course you can tailor the overridden behaviour any which way you want.

Answer (score -1):

I would avoid using an array to model an hash at all. In other words, don't construct the array of pairs in the first place. I'm not being facetious or dismissive. I'm speaking as someone who has used arrays of pairs and (even worse) balanced arrays many times, and always regretted it.

Comment: 1. doesn't answer the question, 2. too subjective and bad advice. I've constructed hash using array many times and never regretted it.

Comment: Too subjective *and* bad advice. Impressive. :-)

Comment: All's well that ends well. :-)